# Setting UIView.transform to arbitrary translate CGAffineTransform does nothing

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, rendering, cgaffinetransform

I have a `UIView` called `container` that I want to move (offset) using affine transfrom. This view contains `UIImageView` and is a subview of `UICollectionViewCell`.

So *it should be simple*:

```
container.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(100, 200) //render container 100 points right and 200 points down
```

Instead *it is very hard*, because theat code does not do *anything*. The view is rendered excatly on the same place as if I delete that line. So I added 'print' to verify what affine translation was set:

```
container.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(100, 200)
print(container.transform) //prints: CGAffineTransform(a: 1.0, b: 0.0, c: 0.0, d: 1.0, tx: 100.0, ty: 200.0)
```

That seems all right. So I tried rotating the `container` view instead with `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation` and it rotates the view just not around its center as it should according to [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/transform). I tried different combinations of translate, rotation and scale transforms just to find that the affine transformation matrixes set are OK, but attributes `tx` and `ty` seems to be ignored and `a, b, c` and `d` seems to be using different anchor point then the centre of the view (cannot say what that point is).

Any ideas on what can be causing this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

There must be something like auto layout messing things up for you. In the absence of outside influence, setting a view's affine transform to CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(100, 200) will shift it right 100 points and down 200. I verified this by making a new Single View Project in Xcode and changing the viewDidLoad method in the ViewController.swift class to:

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor();

    let container = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,100,100));
    container.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor();
    container.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(100, 200);
    view.addSubview(container);
}
```

As expected this makes the green container view appear 100 points to the right and 200 points down, even though its frame is (0,0,100,100).

So please check for auto layout and other such things that might influence the placement of this view, and if you can't find anything please post more code. Also, if your container view doesn't have a background color, please give it one so that you can see its position directly, instead of deducing its position by looking at the image view.

n.b. Setting a view's transform doesn't actually move the view itself, it just changes how/where it draws its content.

Comment: I know. I did similar test myself before posting. Normally, translate transformation works fine. The question is why it is not working in my case? Thank you for the tip with background color, I did it and it just verified that the container indeed is where it should be.

Comment: @drasto If I'm understanding you right, the container is where you want it to be (offset by 100,200) but the image view inside of it is up and to the left of where you want it to be? What is the frame of the image view? That makes it sound like the image view's frame has negative X and Y values for its origin. If that's the case then you would need to figure out who is setting the image view's frame. You can do this by subclassing UIImageView, overriding its Frame and Bounds properties, and using breakpoints in them to see if they are being changed.

Comment: By the way, I don't know what your exact circumstances are, but in general I think you should stay away from doing translation transforms and just use frame offsets. Changing a view's transform can be dangerous because it makes the view's frame "undefined" and that breaks assumptions in a lot of code. For example if you change the frame of a view that has had a non-identity transform applied to it, you probably won't get the results you want.

Comment: Thanks, but I know. I actually need to do rotation and translation but for SO question I simplyfied it to just the part that is not working. Rotation part is working as expected and translation is not working when combined with rotation or if used standalone (just for testing, because normally I would just move the frame as you say).